# Consolidate 2 Powershell scripts into one

Tags: powershell

I have two Powershell scripts running at once on my PC doing a similar job. Each one looks for a sting pattern in a log file and then writes a text string to a text file. This updates dynamically so, each time the string changes in the log file, it's updated in the output text file. All works great.

I would like to consolidate both scripts into one Powershell script to make things more efficient. Hope this makes sense. Below is an example of one of the Powershell scripts. Both scripts are the same except the $output file name is different and the $patterns are different. I’d like each string to go the a csv file.

```
 $log = "LogFile.txt"
 $output = "ExampleOutput.txt"

 $patterns = @("GroupEvents: Linedup for group (.*), subgroup", 
               "Workout(.*)", 
               "GroupEvents: Started in group (.*), subgroup", 
               "Run Device Selected: (.*)")

 function ProcessLog {
     [CmdletBinding()] Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$item)

     Write-Output "Running with $item"

     foreach($pattern in $patterns)
     {
         $save = (Select-String -InputObject $item -Pattern $pattern | % { 
 $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value })

         if(-not [string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($save))
         {
             $save.Trim('(').Trim(')') | Set-Content $output
             return
         }
     }
 }

 Get-Content -Tail 0 -Wait -Encoding "UTF8" $log | % { $_ | ProcessLog }
```

I realise this may not be as simple as it sounds and any other ideas are welcome. Perhaps each individual string could be written to a different tab in a comma separated csv

Comment: do you want one script that can do _either job depending on how it is called_ OR do you want one script that does both jobs at the same time? ///// what have you tried? how did it not work as wanted?

Comment: Hi Lee, I need one script which handles both jobs at the same time but outputs to just one file, ideally a csv or individual spreadsheet cells. I have not tried anything specific as I literally have no idea where to start with combining the two scripts! As I currently have it, it works but I would rather have everything in one place. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: unless you really need it, i would write a 3rd script that combines the two output from the others. [*grin*] the `Import-Csv` cmdlet will merge two files if they have the same header line. ///// another option would be to re-write your current script as a function that accepts parameters - the pattern set, the target files, and the output file. once you have that working, you can simply call the function twice in one script.

Comment: if all that is different between the two scripts is the pattern set and the output file ... why don't you just expand the pattern set? make a 3rd script to test with, change the output file name, add the 2nd pattern set to it, and see what happens ... [*grin*]